# Проблема с RSA и сокетами в Python

Tags: python, многопоточность, сервер, криптография, rsa

Пытаюсь сделать так: сервер генерирует rsa ключи, передает публичный ключ клиенту, клиент получает ключ, шифрует им сообщение, и отправляет его серверу, сервер его расшифровывает, и выводит. Но что в сервере что в клиенте выходит исключение:

```
  blocksize = common.byte_size(priv_key.n)
  AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'n'
```

Код клиента:

```
import socket
import rsa

conn = socket.socket()
conn.connect( ("192.168.1.102", 50) )

bufrecv = conn.recv(4096)
server_pub = bufrecv.decode("utf8")
text = "text".encode("utf8")
bufq = rsa.encrypt(server_pub, text)
conn.send(bufq)
```

Код сервера:

```
import socket
import rsa
import threading

def client_function(socket, sock_ip):
   print("New client connected!")
   socket.send(str(server_pub).encode("utf8"))
   buffer = socket.recv(4096)
   buffr = rsa.decrypt(server_priv, buffer)
   print(buffr.decode("utf8"))
print("Generating RSA keys...")
(server_pub, server_priv) = rsa.newkeys(2048)
print("OK!")
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(("", 50))
sock.listen(100)
print("Wait clients...")
while True:
  (socket_ap, addr) = sock.accept()
  client_thread = threading.Thread(target=client_function, args=(socket_ap, add$
  client_thread.start()
  del(socket_ap)
  del(addr)
```

Comment: Вы неправильно преобразуете/обрабатываете строковое представление публичного ключа.  Получайте строковое представление ключа следующим образом `server_pub.save_pkcs1()` и преобразуйте его в PublicKey на клиенте `rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1(bufrecv)`. Также обратите внимание на порядок аргументов в encrypt и decrypt - первым аргументом должно быть сообщение, вторым ключ.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!